# How to get pure base topo map without any human made things?

Tags: vector, atlas, basemap

I need detailed world map (preferably vector), just like Google Maps Terrain, but **without** roads, streets, airports etc. Just **pure** base map like an atlas with mountains, deserts, rivers, lakes etc. Preferably vector because I need a high detail level (small island, coastline etc.). 
I've tried a lot of sources but they're not detailed enough or they contain a lot of roads, names, buildings... which I couldn't remove.

**EDIT**: And, why this url gives me a BLACK image? Shouldn't it be a terrain?
https://mt1.google.com/vt?lyrs=t&x=1326&y=3143&z=13

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider this: [Natural Earth II is a raster map dataset that portrays the world environment in an idealized manner with little human influence](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-2/)? Can be combined with the regular [vector data form Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/).

Comment: Yes I know it. It is very good, but unfortunately the scale is too big...

Comment: Then you should consider making your own base-map, starting with a digital elevation model (DEM) - or digital terrain model, to be more precise. You could use SRTM-data, available worldwide, e.g. here: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/ - if you need more details, look if there is more detailed data for the region you're interested in (like lidar-data). Add rivers from HydroSheds (derived from SRTM): https://hydrosheds.cr.usgs.gov/ - use smooth($geometry) in geometry-generator to cut edges. Add more details from other sources like OpenStreetMap

Comment: But be aware that rivers often changed a lot in the last 200 years, not only due to natural changes (floods that create new river-beds), but especially due to human intervention. As far as I know, there is no good dataset for pre-modern eras - you have to model that yourself and that's a really painstaiking work, involving detailed study of historical sources. Have a look to this map of changing Danube Delta over centuries: https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Dun%C4%83rii#/media/Fi%C8%99ier:Danube_Delta_evolution.gif - and it continues to change every day...

Comment: Coastlines can be extracted from OpenStreetMap in a very detailed shape that should be good enough

Comment: How to extract coastlines from OSM?

Comment: There are several ways, like overpass turbo with query natural=coastline, you may use the wizard to create the correct query here: https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Comment: See also here: https://github.com/osmcode/osmcoastline and Google for more options to extract OSM data. There are possibilities to do that directly in QGIS

Comment: Its too complicated for me. I'm wonder why there is no such map already prepared...